# Firebase Function Error: could not handle the request + Next App

Tags: node.js, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

This might seem like a repeated question but i promise I've made sure
to check every related ones but non solve my problem

I am deploying a nextjs app on Firebase hosting using cloud functions,
the app does deploy and gives me back the hosting URL of [app
link](https://webavocat.web.app/). visiting the URL i got this 403 forbidden error;

```
Your client does not have permission to get URL /nextServer/ from this server.
```

Which I fixed by adding **allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers as function invoker** at function permission.

But then, after fixing that I got another error saying:

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

this terminated the function with a log of

```
Function execution took 804 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

This doesn't give any reason why the function crashed which has made fixing it all the more harder. Below is my nextServer function code:

```
const { https } = require("firebase-functions");
const { default: next } = require("next");

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const server = next({
    dev: isDev,
    conf: { distDir: ".next" },
});

const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler();
exports.nextServer = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return server.prepare().then(() => {
        return nextjsHandle(req, res);
    });
});
```

and this is the firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "site": "webavocat",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextServer"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "runtime": "nodejs16",
    "ignore": [
      "**/.vscode/**",
      ".firebase/**",
      ".firebaserc",
      "firebase.json",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/public/**",
      "**/.next/cache/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

The project folder structure is as shown below

[image: Project folder scaffold]

> **Edit 1:**
> Don't really know if this is correct,

```
const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler();
exports.nextServer = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    try {
        return server.prepare().then(() => {
            return nextjsHandle(req, res);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

but i used a **try catch** on the on the server function as @mdobrucki suggested. still no log on the why the function crashed though

Comment: Have you tried catching any exceptions that may be thrown by your function? If so, please post them.

Comment: @mdobrucki that's the issue, the function isn't throwing any exception whatsoever, it just crashed and exit. Though i'm using **try catch block**

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you are using try/catch block? It'd be hard to troubleshoot this issue without a proper error message.

Comment: Alright,  I'm using try catch around the cloud function server. I've just edited the question to reflect this change

Comment: @MSadiq have you found any solution to this? im facing same problem and haven't found any help regarding this so far. if you have found a solution please let me know or post the solution here.

Comment: @salman, no, I never did find a solution, had to later go with Vercel as my boss really needed it hosted fast at the time